# Shopping cart price rule not working accurately in magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7.0.2, I have added a rule (particular category products alone should display Free Shipping method). It works fine when all the products are from single category(given in rule) or from other category(not given in rule) but when cart contains combination of both category then it should not show Free Shipping but it is showing Free Shipping.Please see the attached picture for rule.
[image: Shopping cart price rule]

Please suggest where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it worked.We need to give the condition under Actions tab. Please see the attachment.

[image: Actions]